# Regular expression replace

Tags: regex, text-editor, kate

I have to replace `"something"` in file with `:something`.
My editor is kate can anyone suggest a search expression and placeholder for that.

```
Example

Input

"code"
"name"
"remark"

Output

:code
:name
:remark
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

search for `"(\w+)"`, replace with `:\1`

Comment: am expecting an explanation for "(\w+)" and \1.what r they

Comment: search tutorial grouping and back references

Comment: @dfa can i use it through perl s/g

Comment: A blog post concerning this question/ answer: http://labs.sasslantis.ee/2012/05/kate-and-replace-with-regular-expressions/

Comment: Works as a charm. Thanks. Stress in the need to use parentheses. I used to replace single-line style comments (cpp) to multiple-line style comments (c ansi).

search: `(//)(.*)`
replace: `/* \2 */`

Very useful.

Answer (score 3):

search: (something)
replace: :\1

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't a simple search and replace suitable?
pattern: something
replace: :something